# Reactivecocoa gives a lot of errors when just added to a project

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, swift3, reactive-cocoa

I have just added Reactive cocoa using cocoa pods. After opening a workspace and just trying to compile the project I get a lot of errors on Result and RC pods. What could be wrong?
[image]

Comment: Are you using the Swift 3 version of ReactiveCocoa?

Comment: @Cosyn I don't know, I do not specify the version of it

Comment: Then the version should be 4.2.2 which only support Swift 2.3.